# Unable to forward events from a source Wins server to a custom event viewer bucket in Event Collector

Tags: windows, events, forwarding

After following this post: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/russellt/2016/05/18/creating-custom-windows-event-forwarding-logs/, I keep receiving the following error message on the source server  (via Eventlog-ForwardingPlugin) although I already tried adding "Network Service" to the specified channel and the current subscription is "Source Initiated" and "Network Service" is in the Event Log Reader Group. Any thought on how to fix it? Thanks!

```
"The subscription WEC-*** is created, but one or more channels in the query could not be read at this time."
```

Channel ACL:

```
C:\Windows\system32>wevtutil gl WEC-***

name: WEC-***

enabled: true

type: Operational

owningPublisher: WEC

isolation: Application

channelAccess: O:BAG:SYD:(A;;0x2;;;S-1-15-2-1)(A;;0xf0007;;;SY)(A;;0x7;;;BA)(A;;0x7;;;SO)(A;;0x3;;;IU)(A;;0x3;;;SU)(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-3)(A;;0x3;;;S-1-5-33)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-32-573)(A;;0x1;;;S-1-5-20)

logging:

  logFileName: D:\Logs\***\WEC-***.evtx

  retention: false

  autoBackup: false

  maxSize: 10737418240

publishing:

  fileMax: 1
```

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I'm running into this issue seemingly.

Comment: @Redcoatwright nope unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this in the past on multiple machines by adding the Network Service to the Event Log Readers group but also had to reboot.  In my case it was for the additional rights for the Security log.